# How do I get previously opened site url in sharepoint 3.0?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, wss-3.0

I would like to get in my custom webpart an url address of the site which I was opened just previously before I get to current site(that with my webpart)? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Plain ASP.NET Method of getting the Referrer will work for this.You can easily do this with the [**Request.UrlReferrer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)

Comment: Any example of using this property, please...  It doesn't work if I paste it to my code. (I import System.Web namespace.)

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer doesn't work. It redirects page always to itself. :(